# combine data of foreign key table and primary key table using django rest api

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to display all buyers with book names.

```
output needed:
{
"city"
"buyer_name"
"book_name"
}
```

I have the code as follows, but the output is different, i am getting book_id instead of book_name. How to get it?
models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
  book_id=models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  book_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  def __str__(self):
     return str(self.book_id)
class Buyer(models.Model):
  buyer_id=models.BigAutoField(primar_key=True)
  buyer_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  book_id=models.ForeignKey(Book,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.buyer_id)
```

serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model=Buyer
      fields=['city','buyer_name','book_id']
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST']
class BuyerList(request)
  buyerlist=Buyer.objects.all()
  ser=BookSerializer(buyerlist,many=True)
  return Response(ser.data)
```

Comment: btw, you should not add the `_id` suffix to you FK fields. It should be `book = ForeignKey(Book..`. Django will automatically add the `_id` in the database, I bet your db column is currently `book_id_id`

Comment: @pleasedontbelong ok sure  noted, i will change it

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model=Buyer
      fields=['city','buyer_name','book_id__book_name']
      extra_kwargs = {'book_id__book_name': {'label': 'book_name'}}
```

Comment: I tired it, but its giving error as 
`Field name  'book_id__book_name' is not valid for model Buyer.`